# Transformer secondary conductor protection: how do NEC 240.21(C) and NEC 240.4(B) make sense together?

Tags: electrical-engineering, standards

NEC 240.21 says all ungrounded circuit conductors require overcurrent protection, with a list of exceptions:

[image]

One of those exceptions is 240.21(C):

[image]

[image]

240.4(B) says that if you're under 800 amps, you can up-size your breaker to the next available size. But what I don't understand is the text of 240.21(C). It says the conductors connected to the secondary don't have to have protection, and also that the up-sizing of the (non-existent) protection isn't allowed. Why would you say "You're not allowed to up-size the breaker" right after saying "You're not required to have a breaker at all?" I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Aren't they saying 240.4(B) does NOT apply, which means no breaker is required.

Answer (score 1):

See 450.3 and tables 450.3(A) and (B), 240.21(C) says the conductors connected to the secondary don't have to have protection *at the point where the conductors receive their supply*.
It's often not the case that they need no protection at all, its just that the protection can be down stream from the transformer, like a main breaker in a panel.
When applying these tap rules you can't use 240.4(B)